# disable zoom in phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am opening an ASPX page in Phonegap using window.open("page.aspx"). It's opening fine. But how do I disable the zooming of that page?
I've tried using 

but this didn't help.
here is my index.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.close Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum- scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://google.com/', '_blank', 'location=no');

    }
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using the inAppBrowser if the page you're showing doesn't have disabled zooming.

Answer (score 1):

The value in your <meta> tag,

> user-scalable=no

should disable zooming. Also it make sure attribute values are properly formed. For example:

`maximum-scale=1.0`

instead of

> maximum- scale=1.0

This may possibly be causing the viewport properties for not rendering. Using the

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

scrolling should be disabled in inAppBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

I guess this stops the touch events getting to the topmost element.

It also stops the 'bouncing'